# HTML5: Attributes are not recognized after being added with JS / Jquery

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, angular6

Well, I'm stuck with this. 
I'm adding 2 attributes to an input but Angular does not recognize them for validation. What I can be doing wrong?

This is my HTML

```
<input type="text" id="idDOC" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="person.DOC_PERSON" #kind_doc="ngModel" name="dni_persona"  required>
```

This is my component.ts

```
document.getElementById("idDOC").setAttribute("maxlenght", "9");
document.getElementById("idDOC").setAttribute("pattern", "^[0-9]{8}$");
```

this is the console: (I placed in the input: '333333333333')
[image]

The pattern and the maxlenght are there! But after of ng-reflect-model, Idk what's happening, some suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This.

> HTML

```
<input type="text" id="idDOC" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="person.DOC_PERSON" 
#kind_doc="ngModel" name="dni_persona" [maxlength]="maxLength" [pattern]="inputPattern"  required>
```

> JS

```
maxLength = 9;
pattern= /^[0-9]{8}$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a typing mistake in your code

It should be `maxlength` instead of `maxlenght`

```
document.getElementById("idDOC").setAttribute("maxlength", "9");
```

Why are you accessing DOM directly to setAttribute?. This is not the right practice in Angular. you can add it in your template directly.